# a replacement for xslt transformation

Tags: java, xslt, architecture, software-design

I am working on a project that currently uses a bunch of very big xslt files.
we use those xslt's to translate an XML from our system to an XML that the other system can read.
Our system actually receives JSONs which we actually save as XMLs just for those xslts.

We are now thinking about a way to replace the xslt with something simpler, but we have a restriction:
Those xslt's are modified by outside people (which work on the other system), so just refactoring them is not an option, since its only a temporary solution until they will become ugly again. also, we still need to find a way to let those people change the way we transform the XML - preferably without teaching them how to code.

Since our system is written in java, we would also like our solution to be supported by one of the major java frameworks.

I was thinking about a sort of rule engine with XQuery for customization, but I am not sure if that is a valid solution.
Another idea I found was to just use ruby, since many people say that it does the job better. but I fear that the teaching overhead will be too great.

I would really appreciate any ideas you might have for solving this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Without teaching them to code? If they modify XSLT stylesheets, they must have a good grasp of XSLT. Also, I think I am confused with the "systems". You receive JSON, convert it to XML, transform it to another XML ... and convert it back to JSON?

Comment: they learned how to modify xslt (so they do technically code), but their grasp of it seems to be quite basic.
I am sorry about the confusion. what I meant was:
we get JSON, do our logic, then create an XML which is later transformed with the xslt and sent to the other system.

Comment: If I understood correctly now, your real problem is that the people maintaining your XSLT stylesheets do not know how to use XSLT in a clean (or efficient, or functional) way. Would you agree?

Comment: yes. and I can't teach them how to (its also worth mentioning that I myself don't have experience with xslt, but I do have a strong reason to suspect that those XSLT's are not efficient). I want to design a solution which will allow the same flexibility but in a cleaner way.

Comment: I guess XSLT is "a sort of rule engine with XQuery for customization". If you want something less powerful than XSLT then one approach is to define a mini-transformation language that does the transformations you actually need, and then translate that into XSLT for execution. As for the performance, putting a powerful tool into the hands of people who don't understand it fully is always inviting tehm to produce something that works but performs badly.

Comment: It does seem that XSLT is the the best way to work in my case. although I constantly hear from my team that it is hard to maintain, I can't seem to find a better solution.

Comment: Yes, it's the right tool for the job but it's a tool that requires some familiarity to use properly; you can end up in a mess if you try and use it with zero experience/training.